# Can't find virtio_pci.ko(or virtio-pci.ko) in Centos8

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos8

I want do some changes in virtio_pci.ko, so I plan to make a ko from kernel source using current kernel header.

I have tested in Centos7, I can recompile a initramfs-xxx.img to let it load my virtio_pci.ko(which locate at `/lib/modules/xxxx/kernel/drivers/virtio/virtio_pci.ko.xz`), but in Centos8(names virtio-pci.ko, you can find it by `lspci -v` if your guest has virtio device), I can't find it.

Does anyone know how to find it and replace it?

Comment: `find /lib/modules -name "virtio-pci.ko*"` : Nothing. ........... `dnf provides */virtio-pci.ko*` : No Matches found.

Comment: @Knud I did some update

Comment: virtio-pci depends on config. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/virtio/Kconfig#L29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virtio_pci` was built into kernel not as a module, that can be check using file `/boot/config-4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64`

```
# cat /boot/config-4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64 | grep VIRTIO
CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=m
CONFIG_SCSI_VIRTIO=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_NET=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO=y
CONFIG_VIRTIO_PCI=y
```

- `m` is for module
- `y` is for kernel included

Comment: so, I can't change it without compilng new kernel?